# how to block all incoming trafic for all ports from all except subnet ips

Tags: linux, iptables

how to block all incoming traffic for all ports from all except subnet ips

i try block all incoming connections from all except

these ips

> 199.27.128.0/21
> 173.245.48.0/20
> 103.21.244.0/22
> 103.22.200.0/22
> 103.31.4.0/22
>
> 141.101.64.0/18
>
> 108.162.192.0/18
> 190.93.240.0/20
> 188.114.96.0/20
> 197.234.240.0/22
> 198.41.128.0/17
> 162.158.0.0/15

by using linux  centos 6 iptables
that's will help to control all incoming traffic
i try many command but it's not help me

Answer (score 0):

You can set white list to INPUT chain, and drop other packets. Here is am example:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 199.27.128.0/21 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -s 173.245.48.0/20 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -s 103.21.244.0/22 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -s 103.22.200.0/22 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -s 103.31.4.0/22 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -s 141.101.64.0/18 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -s 108.162.192.0/18 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -s 190.93.240.0/20 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -s 188.114.96.0/20 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -s 197.234.240.0/22 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -s 198.41.128.0/17 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -s 162.158.0.0/15 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```